# Задача про долю символа на С

Tags: c

Дан текст. Определить в нем все слова, в которых доля данного символа максимальна.
пример:
Текст: "Veni, vidi, vici" ( "Пришел, увидел, победил.»).
Символ: "i".
Результат: слова "vidi", "vici", доля символа равна 0,5.
Вот что накидал, выводит почему-то весь список, а не у кого максимальная доля.

`#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
int count_symbol, num_of_elements, i, g;
float new_part_of_num, part_of_num, length;
char element[80], symbol;
part_of_num = 0;
printf("enter nubmer of elements in array:");
scanf("%d", &num_of_elements);
char result[80]="";
printf("enter symbol:");
symbol = getchar(); getchar();getchar();
for (i = 0; i<num_of_elements; i++){
    count_symbol = 0;
    printf("enter element:");
    gets(element);
    length = strlen(element);
    for(g=0; g<length; g++){
        if (element[g] == symbol)
        count_symbol++;
        }
        new_part_of_num = count_symbol/length;
    if (new_part_of_num >= part_of_num){
        new_part_of_num = part_of_num;
        strcat(result, element);
        strcat(result, " ");}
}
printf ("result: %s\n",result);
getchar();
return 0;
}`

Comment: Придется делать в два прохода. Первым циклом пройтись по тексту и  определить максимальную долю заданного символа. Вторым циклом вывести слова с максимальной долей символа.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если доля в очередном слове такая же, как максимальная, добавить слово к списку.
Если доля в очередном слове больше, чем максимальная, начать новый список (старый ещё очистить надо). Что-то вроде:

```
  if (new_part_of_num = part_of_num){
        strcat(result, element);
        strcat(result, " ");
    }
  if (new_part_of_num > part_of_num){
        new_part_of_num = part_of_num;
        strcpy(result, element);
        strcat(result, " ");
    }
```

Comment: да, я понял, спасибо за помощь!